# phpbb - how to restrict access to Board index

Tags: forum, phpbb

my client wants me to create a series of websites, each with its own forum.
i have installed and played around with phpbb before and it is my understanding that each installation is capable of creating  many forums. i already created a few using the same installation in another project.

in each forum's "main page"  there is a link to the "Board index" where the list of all forums can be seen and accessed.

in this project i  would this "Board index" not to be available, so users can not navigate between forums - can this be done?

a little background:  there won't really be many websites, just many domains.
all domains will point to the same address, where the url will be analyzed and content would be "pulled" from the database accordingly. part of the content is the link the a specific forum inside the forums system.

we do not want a person that requested "baby-toys.com"  to realize that a forum for
"ninja-killers" is also available..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit your template. The solution is described here: 
http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=1726095